# Abnormally High Nand and Host writes in a SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, hardware-failure, storage, physical-wear

I have SK Hynix SC308 SSD in a laptop. The SSD is roughly 4 years old. I don't know if it is a bug or something but the Nand and Host writes are excruciatingly high; in orders of 10^10 GB magnitude. One peculiar thing is that both Nand and Host writes update to couple of GBs every second. My laptop is working perfectly fine there is no malware and Windows 10 is up to date.

SSD benchmark on CrystalDiskInfo:

[image]

Comment: These numbers look impossible. I think CrystalDiskInfo is misreading the disk data.

Comment: I don't think so because CrystalDiskInfo is literally reading the SMART values provided by SSD.

Answer (score 1):

According to the displayed numbers, in four years you wrote 1335813198 GB of data to
the disk.
A year has 365 days, so we have in total 1460 days.
Per day, this makes 1335813198 / 1460 = 914940 GB or about 915 TB.

This is evidently impossible.

CrystalDiskInfo is clearly misreading the data,
or the disk's firmware is reporting wrong values.

Apart from this, according to the other SMART parameters, the disk is clearly
in good health.